Orleans IPersistentState POCO Namespace Versioning problems
I'm using  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Orleans.Sdk" Version="8.2.0" /> To generate a serializer for a pretty simple record:
 namespace BaseNamespace.OldNameSpace;
 [GenerateSerializer, Alias("MyRecord")]
 public sealed record MyRecord
 {
    [Id(0)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Id(1)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
 }

I have a grain with the following constructor:
public sealed class MyRecordGrain([PersistentState(stateName: "MyRecordValue", MyRecordStorageKey")] IPersistentState<MyRecord> state) : IGrain, IMyRecordGrain

I manage to store the object and retrieve it through the constructor everytime I invoke the Grain. And in SQL Server it looks like this on the PayloadBinary column using select cast(PayloadBinary as varchar(MAX)), * from OrleansStorage:
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "BaseNamespace.OldNameSpace.MyRecord, MyProject.Common.Model",
    "Name": "Anthony",
    "Age ": 14,
},

The problem arises when I'm refactoring heavily class libraries and namespaces. If I change the namespace of MyRecord from namespace BaseNamespace.OldNameSpace; to namespace BaseNamespace.NewNameSpace; and call the grain, the storage serialization will fail with this error, because the namespaces don't match:
    Error from storage provider AdoNetGrainStorage.personCache during ReadStateAsync for grain personCache/PersonCacheKey
 
Exc level 0: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'BaseNamespace.OldNameSpace.MyRecord,  MyProject.Common.Model], System.Collections.Concurrent'. Path '$type', line 1, position 263.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, String qualifiedTypeName)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)

If I change back the namespace to BaseNamespace.OldNameSpace everything works fine. I know that I should add an alias to the record classes so they support different versionings, but how could I avoid this namespace refactoring error? Why does the serialized data need to store about the assembly and the namespace if I'm already providing that information in the constructor of the grainIPersistentState<MyRecord>?
Thanks!

My unerstanding that it's implemented like this to be sure that you're not doing anything harmful with your state. If you want more control on the state - you can make your own repository for grain's state and use it wihout orleans involved at all. If you're asking about this particular desing decision - you can ask in orleans discussions https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/discussions

Answered in https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/discussions/9085
Had to tweak the JsonSerializer configuration to:
siloBuilder.Configure<OrleansJsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
})

